# Problem with my domain registerd with AWS but pointing to gandi.net

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

Just registered my domain ".in" but when I access the domain via the browser it redirects to gandi.net landing page. Checked whois and all the details are fine pointing to me as the registered person.
Any ideas if this is cached and takes time to updated the nameservers to aws.
[Gandi.net](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HYtp.jpg)

Created a static website on a S3 bucket and pointed the A record for the domain to the S3 bucket. Still not working?

Comment: FYI, Gandi operates the domain registrations for AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the nameservers were not the same as the NS record in the hosted zone against the domain name. Updated that and now it works